# I can not change the date of the first empty orphan commit

Tags: git

I initialised a new branch as an empty orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan site-gatsby
git reset --hard
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initializing «site-gatsby» branch"
git push --set-upstream site-gatsby
```

And I ran `git rebase -i --root` to pick the first commit. I modified `git-rebase-todo`:

```
pick 95c5e3ea Initializing «site-gatsby» branch # empty
exec GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300" git commit --amend --date "Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300"
```

But I received the advice:

```
Executing: GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300" git commit --amend --date "Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300"
interactive rebase in progress; onto 9170e962
Last commands done (2 commands done):
   pick 95c5e3ea Initializing «site-gatsby» branch # empty
   exec GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300" git commit --amend --date "Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300"
No commands remaining.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'site-gatsby' on '9170e962'.


Initial commit

No changes
You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so would make
it empty. You can repeat your command with --allow-empty, or you can
remove the commit entirely with "git reset HEAD^".
warning: execution failed: GIT_COMMITER_DATE="Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300" git commit --amend --date "Wed Aug 9 12:20:00 AM 2020 -0300"
You can fix the problem, and then run git rebase --continue
```

I tried with `git commit --allow-empty` and `git rebase --continue`, but after pushing, it did not change the commit date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `--allow-empty` to your `git commit --amend ...` command.

---

An empty commit is easy to rewrite : just create a new one, with the author/committee/dates you want.

If you want to rebase other commits on top of it : use the `--onto` option of `git rebase`

```
# rebase on top of new commit commits since your initial empty commit :
git rebase --onto <new> 95c5e3
```